# Построчный итератор в файле через классы

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, итераторы

Требуется сделать объект класса итерируемым:

```
for line in File('/Users/root/Documents/eve.txt'):
    print(line)
```

Класс объявляется так:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, path_to_file):
        self.path = path_to_file
```

Далее я переопределяю методы `iter` и `next` так:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    curr_str = 0
    with open(self.path, 'r') as f:
        str = f.readlines()[curr_str]
    curr_str += 1
    if str == '':
        raise StopIteration
    return str
```

В итоге у меня выводится лишь первая строка и происходит зацикливание, к следующей строке я перейти не могу и т. к. эта строка не пустая, то и `StopIteration` не срабатывает.

Подскажите, как мне считать первую строку в файле, затем вторую, и так далее, и, когда наткнусь на пустую, то выйти из цикла.

Comment: Но объект `f` уже реализует интерфейс построчного итератора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from open(self.path)
```